# Azure API Mangagement & Web API best practices

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, serverless-architecture

We are going to develop Web API using Asp.net core 2.2

Now we want to use it as serverless, so decided to use API Management (APIM) for the same.

When we started looking into how to deploy API in APIM, it seems, we 1st need to deploy API in App Service and then configure it in APIM.

As in this case, we are **not** going with serverless architecture (i.e. paying only for calls) and we are paying for both i.e. App Service and APIM (to have under VNet, £1500 more)

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While going thru more on this, i found that we also can write Azure functions using [Visual Studio code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-vs-code) OR [Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs). Hopefully it will be similar kind of development experience as we have with Web API.

So with Azure Functions, it will be serverless architecture.

Only issue is that AzureFunctions@Edge is not available as of now and we need to use 3rd party CDN like CloudFlare for the same.